# Send an email with an attach file from the UI with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, base64, email-attachments

I have a situation where I need to send an email when a pdf file attached, but we're not storing that file anywhere, what we're doing is having the API send the file as base 64 to the front-end for display and download, so I've been checking how the front-end could send the email with an attachment but I haven't found a way to do it
Any of you have any idea how I could do it? or could you give us any recommendation please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.